# selecting numpy array axis by int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access systematically a numpy array's axis.  For example, suppose I have an array

```
a = np.random.random((10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))
# choosing 7:9 from axis 2
b = a[:, :, 7:9, ...]
# choosing 7:9 from axis 3
c = a[:, :, :, 7:9, ...]
```

Typing colons gets very repetitive if I have a high dimensional array.  Now, I want some function `choose_from_axis` such that

```
# choosing 7:9 from axis 2
b = choose_from_axis(a, 2, 7, 9)
# choosing 7:9 from axis 3
c = choose_from_axis(a, 3, 7, 9)
```

So, basically, I want to access an axis with a number.  The only way I know how to do this is to use `rollaxis` back and forth, but I am looking for a more direct way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you may be looking for [take](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0,100, (3,4,5))
>>> a[:,1:3,:]
array([[[61,  4, 89, 24, 86],
        [48, 75,  4, 27, 65]],

       [[57, 55, 55,  6, 95],
        [19, 16,  4, 61, 42]],

       [[24, 89, 41, 74, 85],
        [27, 84, 23, 70, 29]]])
>>> a.take(np.arange(1,3), axis=1)
array([[[61,  4, 89, 24, 86],
        [48, 75,  4, 27, 65]],

       [[57, 55, 55,  6, 95],
        [19, 16,  4, 61, 42]],

       [[24, 89, 41, 74, 85],
        [27, 84, 23, 70, 29]]])
```

This will also give you support for tuple indexing. Example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
>>> a[:,:,(0,1,3)]
array([[[ 0,  1,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 15],
        [16, 17, 19],
        [20, 21, 23]]])
>>> a.take((0,1,3), axis=2)
array([[[ 0,  1,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 15],
        [16, 17, 19],
        [20, 21, 23]]])
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this without the slicing. That is, just take a.take('all', axis=3)?

Answer (score 7):

You could construct a slice object that does the job:

```
def choose_from_axis(a, axis, start, stop):
    s = [slice(None) for i in range(a.ndim)]
    s[axis] = slice(start, stop)
    return a[s]
```

For example, the following both give the same result:

```
x[:,1:2,:]
choose_from_axis(x, 1, 1, 2)

# [[[ 3  4  5]]
#  [[12 13 14]]
#  [[21 22 23]]]
```

as does the example in the question:

```
a = np.random.random((10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10))
a0 = a[:, :, 7:9, ...]
a1 = choose_from_axis(a, 2, 7, 9)

print np.all(a0==a1)   # True
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is great.  I was also wondering whether it is possible to do the same with tuples as numpy array accepts tuples as index set.